# Subtracting dates from date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to subtract posted date from this day's date.

```
$subs_date = $_POST['pv']; // user gives how many dates he wants to subtract
$date = (date("Y-m-d"));
$new_date = strtotime ( '-'.$subs_date.'day' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
echo $new_date;
```

This gives me result:
1353884400

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with DateTime->sub() http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.sub.php

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P' . $_POST['pv'] . 'D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do, assuming your code works:

```
$subs_date = $_POST['pv']; // user gives how many dates he wants to substract
$date = (date("Y-m-d"));
$new_date = strtotime ( '-'.$subs_date.'day' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;

//add this:
$new_date = date('m-d-Y', $new_date);
echo $new_date;
```